# FFMPEG skipping x segments ahead, expired from playlists

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to re-stream an M3U8 stream to an rtmp server but I'm often seeing this:

```
Skipping 1 segments ahead, expired from playlists
```

This causes the output stream playback to pause and lag after a while.

I'm using the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -thread_queue_size 8192 -i http://demo.m3u8 -c:a aac -c:v h264 -ar 44100 -vf scale=640:-1 -hide_banner -bf 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vprofile baseline -preset superfast -segment_list_flags live -segment_list_size 300 -segment_time 300 -hls_list_size 300 -hls_time 300 -flvflags no_duration_filesize -f flv rtmp://myserver
```

Is there a way to prevent this issue to ensure a smooth playback?